# asp.net: how to access contents of a textbox inside the cell of a table that was created from the code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm having trouble accessing the contents of a textbox inside the cell of a table that was created from the code behind. In my small program, the table is pre-populated with a student's name (cell A1). A textbox is added to the cell below it (cell A2). The user enters Pass or Fail into the textbox and clicks submit. At that point a message should read, "The students status was changed to (whatever the user entered)". This is the problem -- since the textbox ID (student1) is assigned in the code behind, the textbox ID does not yet exist in the context.

```
//Code Behind

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label nameStudent = new Label()
        {
            Text = "Annie McDonald"
        };

        TableCell nameCell = new TableCell();
        nameCell.Controls.Add(nameStudent);
        NameRow.Cells.Add(nameCell);

        TextBox status = new TextBox()
        {
            ID = "student1",
            Text = "Pass or Fail"
        };

        TableCell statusCell = new TableCell();
        statusCell.Controls.Add(status);
        StatusRow.Cells.Add(statusCell);
    }

    protected void sumbitChange_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Confirm.InnerText = "The students status was changed to " + student1.Text;

    }


<body>

<form id="form1" runat="server">
<asp:Table ID="StudentRoster" runat="server">
<asp:TableRow ID="NameRow" runat="server" />
<asp:TableRow ID="StatusRow" runat="server" />
</asp:Table>

<asp:Button ID="sumbitChange" text="Submit" runat="server" OnClick="sumbitChange_Click"/>

    <p id="Confirm" runat="server"></p>
</form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find the TextBox inside the TableRow. Try the code below:

```
protected void sumbitChange_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox student1 = StatusRow.FindControl("student1") as TextBox;
    Confirm.InnerText = "The students status was changed to " + student1.Text;

}
```

I have tested and it is working.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you misunderstand the way ASP.NET WebForms works. You usually declare the controls in the `*.aspx` or `*.ascx` file, assign them an ID and access them via code behind (`*.aspx.cs` or `*.ascx.cs`).

In your case this would look like this:

***.aspx file**

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">   
    <p class="someFancyInformationStyle"><asp:Label ID="statusLabel" runat="server"></asp:Label></p>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Status</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><asp:Label ID="nameLabel" runat="server"></asp:Label></td>
            <%-- Or even better, use a drop down --%>
            <td><asp:TextBox ID="statusTextBox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
        </tr>
        ...
    </table>
</form>
```

**Code behind file:**

```
protected void sumbitChange_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    statusLabel.Text = "The students status was changed to " + statusTextBox.Text;
}
```